# Biot_Savart law for bounded current systems

Tags: partial-differential-equations, electromagnetism

I have a PDE I don't know how to solve, which is a result of a physics problem related to the Biot-Savart equation.

The PDE in question is an equation for B:

$$\text{curl}(B)=\text{del}(\phi)$$

where $\phi$ is a known function in $3$D space.

- Additional information:

*div* and *curl* of this equation are identically zero.

Any suggestions?

I can't apply a Biot-Savart approach to this equation as it is not an unbounded problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Are we still assuming $div(B) = 0 $ as is the case for the magnetic field. Are you familiar with the concept of the vector potential? What further information can be provided about $\phi$?

Comment: The solution of this equation for $B$ will not be unique as $curl(B + del(\psi) ) = curl(B)$ for any differentiable scalar $\psi$. Do you have any boundary conditions for $B$?